# How do I upload a binary file from Meteor to an external API?

Tags: javascript, meteor, zendesk

My issue: I can't figure out how to send a binary file from a Base64 encoded string in my Meteor Methods using the Zendesk API.

Basically I'm trying to replicate this curl command in Meteor on the server side:

```
curl -u username:password -H "Content-Type: application/binary" --data-binary @file.dat -X POST "https://helpdesk.zendesk.com/api/v2/uploads.json?filename=myfile.dat&token={optional_token}"
```

I am getting a Base64 encoded file from the front-end. Here's my Meteor method:

http://pastie.org/private/irextwfhdbgpknjpjjldw

The upload works but the image is corrupted and I can't open it.

I'm still very new to Meteor and also pretty green about encoding and such, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out a solution to my problem.

I switched from the native Meteor HTTP to the Node request package. It seems to support sending binary data better. Maybe I didn't use it right, but no matter what I did, Meteor HTTP Call would encode my file in weird formats.

So now I decode the base64 dataString with this helper function:

```
    function decodeBase64Image(dataString) {
        var matches = dataString.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/),
            response = {};

        if (matches.length !== 3) {
            return new Error('Invalid input string');
        }

        response.type = matches[1];
        response.data = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');

        return response;
    }
```

Then I set my options

```
options = {
    headers: { 'content-type' : 'application/binary', 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded },
    url: zendeskURI + 'uploads.json?filename=' + args.name,
    body: decodeBase64Image(file).data,
    method: 'POST'
};
```

And i use request to post:

```
        request.post(options, function(error, response, body){
            var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(body);

            callback && callback(null, parsedJSON);
        });
```

Now everything works fine and I'm able to upload binary data to the Zendesk API!